# How can I split street and house number from address field in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I separate via XSLT street and house number? I need to split an address string into two nodes using XSLT. So, for example,

```
<Customer> 
   <ShippingAddress>Test Street 32a-33b</ShippingAddress> 
...
</Customer>
```

Should look like following transformation:

```
<Customer> 
<Street>Test Street</Street> 
<HouseNo>32a-33b</HouseNo> 
</Customer>
```

I think the right approach is to split from the first digit in the string. Someone an idea?

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Can you garantee the format of ShippingAddress (i.e., number will always be last and have no spaces)?

Comment: Yes I can use xslt 2.0 and housenumber will always be last but may have spaces e.g. 'Elmstreet 34 - 36' should be splittet in 'Elmstreet' and '34 - 36'

Comment: It's easy enough to do using `xsl:analyze-string` and the regex `([^0-9]*)([0-9].*)`, returning the two parts as `regex-group(1)` and `regex-group(2)`, but I find it hard to imagine it giving satisfactory results on any real-life data.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit of a late response but I run into the same problem.
After some tweaking, the following worked for me.

Incoming element:

```
<AddressLine1>School straat 1</AddressLine1>
```

XSLT 2.0:

```
<Street>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(AddressLine1, 1, (string-length(AddressLine1)-(string-length(tokenize(AddressLine1,' ')[last()])+1)))"/>
</Street>
<StreetNumber>
    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(AddressLine1,' ')[last()]"/>
</StreetNumber>
```

Output:

```
<Street>School straat</Street>
<StreetNumber>1</StreetNumber>
```

Comment: An efficient solution would find the split point ONCE, then use it to extract the before and after parts.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0, you can use `analyze-string` to use a regex to split the string.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="ShippingAddress">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="^(\D+)(\d.*)$">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <Street><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(regex-group(1))" /></Street>
                <HouseNo><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></HouseNo>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great job. Many thanks. Now I have just one stupid problem. I need to call  '<xsl:template match="ShippingAddress">' within another template. I'm doing my first steps in XSLT :-D.

Comment: At the moment the identity template is doing that. But you can do `<xsl:apply-templates select="ShippingAddress" />` if you really wanted to, assuming you were in a template that matched `Customer`.

Comment: Perfect Tim. Thank you so much. It works. In few seconds I'll post my next question, maybe you'll take a look on it :-D